# CSS issue, targeting font-size in IE8

Tags: css

Please take a look at my site: http://burnett.inigowebdesign.co.uk/local_area

I am using Twitter bootstrap CSS (with HTML5 Boilerplate), Modernizr, and Google fonts using @font-face.

I am using modernizr to test for a browser's support of fontface- it not supported, I need to change the font-size (otherwise it will be far too large)

I am testing the site for compatibility and have noticed in IE8 (and early versions of Safari & Opera) my rules for font-size are being ignored. In particular, the h3 elements in the main list (that you can see on the left in the green box) don't seem to respond to any CSS I apply to them. I am using Firebug to inspect the rules, and can't find any possible conflicts. It even ignores !important. In fact, the only way I can style them at all is to use inline CSS.

What is going on??

Comment: Sorry, yes, corrected. That was a typo in my question, not an error in my code.

Comment: Can you post what style rules you have for changing the font-size, or better yet post a small demo

Comment: _Any_ CSS, or just `font-size` rules? Though if inline CSS is working, it sounds like a specificity bug. Firebug might be determining the cascading based on the rules it knows while the faulty browsers might be cascading the rules incorrectly.

Comment: Validate your HTML to see if you have any open tags or other madness.

Comment: OK, guys, thanks for the replies. Click the link in the OP again now and you'll see a stipped-down version of the problem. The problem seems to stem from the Twitter bootstrap CSS?

Answer (score 0):

[image]The text is differ due to different `font-size` define in each css file.
In `normalize.css` h3 have `1.17em` font size and in `fontface.css` font size define `50px` . It might be possible the browser rendering the file in some different orders.

normalize.css file using this property.

```
h3 {
    font-size: 1.17em;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

fontface.css file using this property.

```
h3 {
    font-size: 50px;
/*  letter-spacing: normal;
    font-weight: normal;*/
    line-height: 36px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Kheema. I don't think that's it though. I've stripped out everything now including all additional CSS files, and it's still not responding to anything. Madness. Maybe this is an issue with Browserstack.

Comment: I see you working on site. Now  fonts are same in IE11 and in FF. lets add another file and see what happened.

Comment: Hi Kheema. No- baffled. I cannot for the life of me understand why I can't target that h3. To make matters worse, BS seems to cache my CSS files. This is how it shows the site in IE8: http://tinyurl.com/nhuhal6

Comment: I have applied an id of 'test' to the first h3 element, and targeted using main ul li h3#test { font-size: 20px !important } Now how the hell can that not be finding it??

Comment: let me check in IE8 testing tool.

Comment: Thank you! I won't change anything for a while so you can see. The code I describe above is still there.

Comment: I found one problem @fontface stlye is not applied in IE8 browser, another issue I found still `2 different properties` are assign to `h3` element. somewhere for `h3` font size is `1.17em` and on another location is `24px` sorry I am repeating myself.. I've posted a screenshot as well in my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I have removed the Twitter boostrap css and normalize.css altogether. But still the problem persists. Maybe you could try refreshing/reloading in your tester now? In browserstack it still looks exactly the same though.

Comment: I see there is no style for h3 anymore and now its taking by default size. I would suggest you to use a `reset.css` file. I hope that will fix this issue

Comment: OK, but I still can't understand how there is no difference between the size of text of the h3 elements, when one of them is clearly targeted using an id selector and parent-child hierarchy AND using the !important rule? Here are 2 screenshots to demonstrate the problem: http://tinyurl.com/nz3zza2 AND in BS: http://tinyurl.com/pv6xly8

Comment: All Browsers have different rendering engines, that why they all behave differently in specific cases. You use CSS specificity as well but font rendering work differently; this is the reason people use `reset.css`. or incase to check the font size issue you may use inline style.

Comment: @Inigo You forgot your semi-colon.

Comment: Kheema I understand what you're saying about reset, but with my CSS I should still expect to see a difference in size between the first h3 and the others, no? I've just added inline CSS, and it has changed. See screenshot: http://tinyurl.com/olzekvs

Comment: Thanks, MiniR. I don't think the semicolon is required if there is only one rule. But I've added it anyway.

Comment: you are using `main ul li h3#test {font-size: 20px !important;}` but in HTML I  can see `ul` is not direct child of `main` element. you can use `div.content ul li h3{font-size: 20px !important;}`

Comment: Thanks, Kheema. You were right, that affected it. Now I can target it using the *test* id selector, but NOT with any class name. Please take a look at the source code now. You'll see one h3 has a CLASS of *test*, and one an ID of *test*. 2 corresponding CSS selectors set up in the fontface.css file. The id one works, the class one doesn't. I don't get it, this is crazy.

Comment: ID can be used only one time in a page so its not good practice to create several ID's; however the classes can be repeat multiple times in a page so you can make a class and hen apply in every `h3` element.

Comment: Yes, Kheema, I realise that. But it doesn't explain why one rule works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, nevermind- it IS working now with the classes (BS caching issue). But I HAVE to add class names to each h3, then target using **div.content ul li h3.classname** If I remove the class attribute, and just use **div.content ul li h3** it doesn't work. I really don't understand why? Thanks for your help though, this is enough for me to get round it I think. +1 for the advice on direct children, although I don't understand this either, I assume it's specific to IE?

Comment: Its happened because previously you were using two different properties to `h3`. And after fixing the previous issue you were not using the right CSS specificity to select h3. Although `ID` have more specificity than `class`.  but in your case you can use `div.content ul li h3{font-size: 20px !important;}`

Comment: If your problem solved can you give vote by accepting the answer .

Comment: "in your case you can use div.content ul li h3{font-size: 20px !important;}"  -- But I can't. That is the code which is on the site now, but it isn't working. Sorry.

Comment: okay what if you remove `font-size` from here. `div.content ul li h3{font-size: 20px !important; /*remove this line*/}` I tested in FF and its works.

Comment: Nothing happens if I remove it- (ie, it is not working in the first place). This issue is only with IE8. Everything works as expected in FF.

Comment: aah man serious issue. by the way by adding the class in each `h3` solves your problem, then use it please. IE8 really sucks.

Comment: Tell me about it! I will. Thanks for help anyway, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: please close this question by accepting the answer.

Comment: FYI, Kheema, I've narrowed this down to a problem with Modernizr: http://tinyurl.com/onl48ok

Comment: Well, thanks for down voting; I'm  familiar with it IE8 version required `.eot` format. Ad few years back it was not same, every browser supports different version of font type. but now all browsers are more lined. still not fully supported.